# Subview containing UITextfield isn't registering tapgesture

Tags: ios, swift

I have a subview with a textfield. I'd like the keyboard to be dismissed when I tap anywhere outside of the textfield, but the problem is that taps within the subview aren't being registered and only taps outside of the subview dismiss the keyboard.

My view has a subview (coverView):

```
var coverView: UIView = {
    let cover = UIView()
    cover.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    cover.backgroundColor = .white
    cover.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 300).isActive = true
    cover.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 300).isActive = true
    cover.clipsToBounds = true
    return cover
}()
```

This coverView has its own ImageView:

```
var coverImageView: UIImageView = {
    let imageView = UIImageView(image: nil)
    imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    imageView.backgroundColor = .white
    imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
    imageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    return imageView
}()
```

The coverView has a UITextfield added to it when tapped:

```
@objc func imageTapped(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {

    guard self.textfield1.text == "" else {return}

    self.coverView.addSubview(textfield1)
    self.textfield1.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.coverView.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    self.textfield1.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.coverView.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
    self.textfield1.becomeFirstResponder()
}
```

If the user taps *anywhere* I'd like the keyboard to dismiss. I do this using the following code:

```
@objc func keyboardDidShow() {        
    let exitTapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(exitKeyboardTap(_:)))
    exitTapGesture.name = "exitTap"
    exitTapGesture.delegate = self
    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(exitTapGesture)
}
```

However, the keyboard only dismisses when I tap **outside** of the coverView. When I tap anywhere inside of the coverView the keyboard does not dismiss.

Comment: try add the self. coverView.addGestureRecognizer(exitTapGesture)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add gesture to coverView

```
private func getTapGesture() -> UITapGestureRecognizer {
       let exitTapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(exitKeyboardTap(_:)))
        exitTapGesture.delegate = self

       return exitTapGesture
    }

@objc func keyboardDidShow() {        

    coverView.addGestureRecognizer(getTapGesture())
    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(getTapGesture())

}
```

Comment: If I add the gesture to coverView it works but then when I tap outside of the coverView it doesn't work. Is there a way to get both without creating an entirely new view?

Comment: Tapping on the coverView removes the keyboard but tapping outside of the view does not (even if I added to both the view and the coverView)

Comment: is your view userInteraction enabled ? or some other view covering your main view?

Comment: its not the same tap gesture .. you are creating new each time you call the function

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213527/discussion-between-jawadali-and-pizza7).

Comment: You are right - I understand. I deleted my previous comment and will mark your answer as correct!